# Is black phosphorous aromatic?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, aromaticity

I know that graphite and boron nitride are aromatic in nature.

In a similar way, can black phosphorous too exhibit aromaticity? Since it is essentially the same having 6 membered rings with lone pair of electrons and vacant d orbitals.

If not, then it would show some double bond character also, right?

Comment: According to: https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2018/NR/C7NR05718K#!divAbstract

[...] Despite the fact that **BP does not show aromaticity** or single atom thickness as graphene, it has something else in common with graphene as we report below [...]

So, as to the aromatic character, it looks like it doesn't have it.

Aside from that, it would be intuitive to guess it by looking at the shape of BP: it is not planar, which is a characteristic of "common" aromatic molecules: delocalization is not favoured

Comment: There.  Are.  No.  Outer.  d.  Valence.  Orbitals.  Period!